# Modifying natbib \citep

Tags: citing, natbib, harvard-style

I need to use a "modified Harvard" citation style for one of my papers, in which the citation should look like

```
(Jones, 1990:99)
```

where the author is Jones, the year is 1990 and the page is 99.

The closest I could get to that is via the natbib command:

```
\citep[99]{jones} yields: (Jones, 1990, 99)
```

But this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I would appreciate any ideas/suggestions.

Thanks!

[EDIT] Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib} 

\title{Hello}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle 

Hello. \citep[99]{jones} 

\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{mybib}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `\setcitestyle{notesep={:}}`in your preamble. It changes the separator from standard `,` to `:`.